# nginx / php-fpm error logging

Tags: php, php-fpm, php5, logging

I'm trying to figure out where the PHP errors are going in my setup.  I'm running nginx as the reverse proxy to PHP-FPM, but I'm not seeing the various **E_NOTICE** or **E_WARNING** messages my app is producing.  The only reason I know they're happening is failed responses and NewRelic catching stack traces.

Here's the logging config:

**nginx.conf**

```
proxy_intercept_errors on;
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
```

**php.ini**

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL
display_errors = Off
display_startup_errors = Off
log_errors = On
log_errors_max_len = 1024
ignore_repeated_errors = Off
ignore_repeated_source = Off
report_memleaks = On
track_errors = On
error_log = syslog
```

**php-fpm.conf**

```
[global]
error_log = /var/log/php-fpm/fpm-error.log

[www]
access.log = /var/log/php-fpm/access.log
access.format = "%t \"%m %r%Q%q\" %s %{mili}dms %{kilo}Mkb %C%%"
catch_workers_output = yes

php_flag[display_errors] = on
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = true
```

**rsyslog.conf**

```
:syslogtag, contains, "php" /var/log/php-fpm/error.log
```

I've configured PHP to log to syslog, however FPM has no syslog function so it's logging to a file.  I don't really care where the errors end up, just that they end up somewhere.

Any clues on how I might get this to work?

Comment: I would try make errors display first (in a test.php file you could manually trigger an error), then put them in a file and so on... . Could be errors triggered are from cli, thus using a different php.ini

Comment: Did you try this? php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on

Answer (score 7):

Your php-fpm.conf file is not set up to send errors to syslog. See below for an example of how to do this.

```
; Error log file
; If it's set to "syslog", log is sent to syslogd instead of being written
; in a local file.
; Note: the default prefix is /var
; Default Value: log/php-fpm.log
error_log = syslog

; syslog_facility is used to specify what type of program is logging the
; message. This lets syslogd specify that messages from different facilities
; will be handled differently.
; See syslog(3) for possible values (ex daemon equiv LOG_DAEMON)
; Default Value: daemon
;syslog.facility = daemon

; syslog_ident is prepended to every message. If you have multiple FPM
; instances running on the same server, you can change the default value
; which must suit common needs.
; Default Value: php-fpm
;syslog.ident = php-fpm

; Log level
; Possible Values: alert, error, warning, notice, debug
; Default Value: notice
;log_level = notice
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure about your assumption for the rsyslog.conf? That is, are you sure all such syslog messages are tagged with lower-case "php"?

Try setting syslog.facility to something like local2 (or local1, or local7) and replacing your rsyslog.conf config-line accordingly:

```
local2.* /var/log/php-fpm/error.log
```

Answer (score 2):

When you're using php-fpm, it appears to override the `php.ini` settings.

The logging most likely needs to be configured in `.../www.conf`.

I uncommented these lines in order to grab the PHP logs.

```
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-errors.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
```

The webserver user and group can also be found in this file under lines similar to this (may differ between unix socket & proxy configuration).

```
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
```

Then it's just a matter of creating the file and configuring it properly.

```
touch /var/log/php-errors.log
chmod 644 /var/log/php-errors.log
chgrp www-data /var/log/php-errors.log
chown www-data /var/log/php-errors.log
```

I believe the log level is still used from `php-fpm.conf` so you may also need to check this.

```
log_level = error
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. But adding this line `log_level = error` would cause an error and stop php-fpm from launching. My php-fpm version is `7.2`.

Answer (score 0):

to get php-fpm errors in nginx error log you need:

as for nginx:  it s enough just basic config

```
# cat default  | grep -v "#"


server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;
 
        index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

}
```

as for php-fpm  the main setting is

```
log_errors = On
```

basically it s enough. but to be on the safe side i would suggest
to put the following block in php-fpm config(/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini) :

```
[PHP]
...
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
display_errors = Off
display_startup_errors = On
log_errors = On
log_errors_max_len = 1024
ignore_repeated_errors = Off
ignore_repeated_source = Off
report_memleaks = On
track_errors = Off
html_errors = On

...
```

after that all php stack traces will be in

```
# tail /var/log/nginx/error.log 
2023/06/20 23:37:06 [error] 20307#20307: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '"asd"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /var/www/html/php1.php on line 2" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /php1.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "localhost"
2023/06/20 23:48:40 [error] 20307#20307: *5 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '"asd"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /var/www/html/php1.php on line 2" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /php1.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "localhost"
2023/06/21 00:18:17 [error] 20307#20307: *7 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '"asd"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /var/www/html/php1.php on line 2" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /php1.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "localhost:4545"
```

if you want to see php stack traces not in nginx erorr file but
instead in a separate file you need to add  **error_log** setting
that is

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
display_errors = Off
display_startup_errors = On
log_errors = On
error_log = /var/log/php-errors.log
log_errors_max_len = 1024
ignore_repeated_errors = Off
ignore_repeated_source = Off
report_memleaks = On
track_errors = Off
html_errors = On
```

also **very important** to create /var/log/php-errors.log manually and set proper
permisssions because php-fpm wont do that and will continue to transfer error
to nginx. so

```
# touch /var/log/php-errors.log
# chown www-data.www-data /var/log/php-errors.log
# systemctl restart php7.0-fpm
```

after that nginx error log /var/log/nginx/error.log will be empty
but all php-errors will be in  /var/log/php-errors.log