# php-fpm access log to rsyslog

Tags: logging, php-fpm, rsyslog, syslog

I am trying to find a solution for getting logs from php72 php-fpm yii2 application behind nginx on several numbers of servers:
at now application writes its logs to files on server disk, yii performs rotation of log files.

But this solution requires fast and large disks that costs $$ and getting logs in one place with shared dir - another problem because acessing files from several servers causes individual log lines to be fragmented.

At the moment I began using promtail/loki, but promtail need to be running on the server with application and gives additional overhead for configuration and operate.

Here comes (I was thought) old good rsyslog, but all my attempts to get access logs from php-fpm failed:

- getting all rsyslog lines to central promtail, not without problems, but it works,
- getting log to rsyslog from pure php-cli scripts - ok,
- yii-scripts - some lack of succes,
- php-fpm - no one: no access logs, no error logs dont get to (r)syslog

what I relied on:

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-log-syslogtarget#$levels-detail

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76229

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67764

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=79342

[nginx / php-fpm error logging](https://serverfault.com/questions/574880/nginx-php-fpm-error-logging)

My configs:

/etc/php.ini

```ini
;error_log = syslog # if change fpm writes nothing to syslog
```

/etc/php-fpm.conf

```ini
error_log = syslog
syslog.facility = local0
syslog.ident = php-fpm
log_level = notice # debug mode results in a constant stream of lines about child processes spawning
```

/etc/php-fpm.d/site.conf

```ini
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
php_admin_value[auto_prepend_file] = /etc/php-fpm.d/prepare_log.php
;php_admin_value[syslog.facility] = local0 # if uncomment php cannot change admin flag value
;php_admin_value[syslog.ident] = php-fpm-$pool # if uncomment php cannot change admin flag value
access.log = syslog
slowlog = syslog
;php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/$pool-error.log
;php_admin_value[error_log] = syslog # if uncomment php cannot change admin flag value
```

/etc/php-fpm.d/prepare_log.php

```php
<?php
        openlog('php', LOG_NOTICE, LOG_LOCAL3);
```

/etc/rsyslog.conf

```
$ModLoad imuxsock 
$ModLoad imjournal
...
*.* action(type="omfwd" protocol="tcp" target="promtail.localdomain" port="1514" Template="RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format" TCP_Framing="octet-counted" KeepAlive="on")
```

There is exists any solutions for such problem without writing logs to the files and read from them? Maybe I dont get things right, maybe I need to look at docker/kubernetes mechanics to get logs, maybe there is a library to write directly to syslog/promtail that doesn't require a lot of application code change